# Multiple transactions for a single payment in bitpay

Tags: transactions, payment, bitpay

Let's say we are 4 people and we want to purchase something that is currently worth 10 coins. When we click the purchase button, we are presented with an address to transfer the coins within 15 minutes.

The question: Should we send the necessary coins in a single transaction? Or is it possible to make (for example) 4 different transactions of (for example) 2.5 btc each, summing in 10 btc? If so, what if one of us cannot make the transfer on time?

Any information/experience is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted BitPay support about the issue and they said that it'll just work.

So we made our payment via 3 different transactions. As soon as all transactions were made, the BitPay window informed us:"This invoice has been paid." At that moment either one of the transactions had a single confirmation or none had any. Then came the confirmations.

*Addendum* - The official response from BitPay support for question on paying via multiple transactions:

> "That should be fine. However with bitcoin you can structure a transaction to be paid
>   from several accounts at one time. That's one of the cool concepts of
>   Bitcoin. I recommend you check it out on wikipedia.
>
> For sake of time your method should be sufficient. Make sure you do
>   sufficient fees to speed up the transaction."

Answer (score 0):

Have one person collect the coins before hand and send in one go. The blockchain will serve as proof.

Comment: I am not asking on how to make "some" bitcoin payment. This is a question about how payment mechanism in BitPay works.